# How do I get the correct CSS width of a parent container when there's text overflow outside of the container (happens with most italic fonts)?

Tags: jquery, css

**Happy Path**

The image below is a happy path where the text doesn't show up outside of the parent element:

[image]

```
> $('#myContainer').width();
462
```

**Text Overflow**

When you go to make the font italic, text appears outside of the parent container. The problem is, I need the text either fully contained within the parent element (orange box) or need to be able to get the full width of the parent including the text overflow on the right side of the box:

[image]

```
> $('#myContainer').width();
462
```

How can this be done? I don't want to clip the text so using the CSS `text-overflow` property doesn't seem help me out.

Here's a fiddle that shows the problem:

- https://jsfiddle.net/troygrosfield/7qwx5h9m/

**UPDATE**: adding the font family '[Aguafina Script](https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/ofl/aguafinascript)' non-italic font overflow case:

[image]

Comment: This is the faux "in browser" italicizing...right. Does this happen with a true italic font?

Comment: Yes, the issue still happens with a true italic font.  The original problem was found when I was using the google fonts "Aguafina Script" which is  italic by nature and has the same issue.  

https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/ofl/aguafinascript

Comment: Can you not just find out whether it is in italics... and if so, increase the container width by x pixels/percent/ems?

Comment: @AdamJeffers, the fonts can range on how much "italic-ness" they have.  So there wouldn't be a one size fits all approach to an increase in parent container with or even padding for that matter.  The fiddle example shows a slight overflow, where as other font-families such as "Aguafina Script" (google font) has a massive overlow when it's not even italicized.

Comment: Hmmm interesting... take a look at this, might be of some help?? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_measuretext.asp

Comment: One way is to add letter spacing ( the amount of italic) check this updated solution https://jsfiddle.net/7qwx5h9m/1/

Comment: You gonna need to use some hack provided here (letter spacing, padding), as you won't be able to calculate this space with JS. In this case, the width of the element is calculated on its content baseline.

Comment: I don’t think those measurements are available (taking italics into regard) in this context (HTML&CSS in a browser.) And what @enguerranws said, seems to be correct (at least the screenshots would support it being the case.) What do you need this for, and how precise do you need it to be? Maybe drawing the text onto a `canvas` and then checking the different [`TextMetrics`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) properties could help? (Haven’t tried it, just spitballing here.)

Comment: Or maybe SVG and [`getComputedTextLength`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength)? (Nope, haven’t tried that one either ;-)

Comment: @AdamJeffers, tried canvas' ``measureText(...)`` feature and it gave me the exact same measurement as the non-canvas parent container.

Comment: @CBroe, it's used for putting text over images so it needs to be quite accurate.  The problem with drawing on canvas it having to repaint the canvas every time the text is resized.  The 4 box corners from above can be dragged by the user to resize the box along with the text inside it.  I'll give the ``getComputedTextLength()`` a shot...

Comment: @PRAH, letter spacing won't work because it won't make the text look natural and there really isn't an easy way to figure out what letter spacing is needed by each font since there are over 750 font possible font options.  So the solution needs to be more dynamic.

Comment: I added the 'Aguafina Script' text overflow case to the original question.  When ``letter-spacing`` css is applied to that text, it loses the "handwriting" feel since the letters are no longer connected.  Another reason why ``letter-spacing`` doesn't work.

Comment: @CBroe, svg's ``getComputedTextLength()`` return the same value as canvas and the original width value.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the elements with italic fonts a padding of around 5px(?) on the right side.

Comment: See some of the comments directly below the main question.  There are some fonts that are italic by nature even without directly having the ``font-style: italic`` styling that have the same issue.  Also, not all font have the same about of overflow.  Some have a lot more that others.